# What can be done with Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, clisp

I started learning CLISP. Should I improve my self. What can be done with this programming language? What's it for. I'd appreciate your answers and comments. Thanks.

Comment: this question will get closed very quickly.  I think you either need to retag it or ask a (specific) question.

Comment: I agree with @griegs. The short answer is Everything can be done in CLISP. But that's only because it's turing complete. Everything can be done in Brainf*ck too. Are you asking what would be a good project to begin learning CLISP with?

Comment: Earlz could you give me some ideas, please?

Comment: @Earlz: If you write an application in brainfuck that opens a GUI window using a brainfuck interpreter (or compiler) which does not offer any behavior that is not part of the brainfuck definition, I'll give you $100.

Comment: @griegs 1.5 yrs and still not closed! you aren't successful as a prophet :) (Unless you meant "very quickly, geologically speaking".)

Answer (score 9):

Common Lisp, of which CLisp is an implementation, is a general purpose language.  You can do with it whatever you want.  For a nice, practical introduction, take a look at [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) by Peter Seibel.

Answer (score 5):

Judging by your comment you're looking for ideas to implement using Common Lisp.

It seems lots of people nowadays are using Project Euler to try out a language: it's a source of fun, small problems that lets you learn some maths too.

Failing that, find an itch that you have - a program that you need - and write that in Common Lisp.